# Economics: inflation, principal, interest

Tags: arithmetic, economics

Can someone help? It has to do with economics:

> A person puts $5$k USD in a savings account each year. Inflation is $2.5\%$ each year. Taxes on this person's interest are $24\%$. This savings account pays $2\%$ each year. This person adds $5$k to this account each year. This goes on for $30$ years. What does this person have in interest, interest after taxes, interest and principal after inflation, and principal after reinvestment each year $1-30$?

I tried this:

Year 1: $5,000= Principle year 1 (P)$; $P\cdot .02=Interest year 1 (I)$; $I \cdot .24=Tax year 1 (T$); $T-I=Interest after tax year one (A)$; $A+P=Interest after tax year one + Principle year one (O$); $O+P= Principle year two (T)$; $T \cdot .025= Principle year two after inflation$ . . . I get a bit lost here, how to maybe formalize it further, reiterate it over 30 years

Comment: Hello, I tried 5000*0.2=Interest, Interest*.24=Tax; Tax-interest= Interest after tax; Interest after tax + principle = Principle year 2; Principle year 2+5000=Principle year 2 after yearly add; Principle year 2 after yearly add*.025= Principle year 2 after yearly add and inflation; I just feel unsure how to streamline this so I don't do it by hand and risk missing some number after 30 times

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  I assume you meant to say interest - tax = interest after tax.  Also, you should edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck rather than leaving that information in the comments, where it might be overlooked.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Hello, thanks. Oh yes. I meant that. Oh okay I can edit my question to show what I tried. I just tried responding to that comment above. Thank you for showing me how to write some mathematical symbols I appreciate it.

Comment: This cries out for a spreadsheet calculation.  Each year is a row.  Show the year number and the balance at the beginning of the year.  Apply the given changes to go from year 0 to year 1.  Copy down.  Done.

Comment: Oh wow yes. I practiced using a spreadsheet. Spreedsheets seem like from god. And your comment really streamlined this process. Thank you tremendously.